# Can I add Javascript to a URL for a frequently visited page?

Tags: javascript

I use Constant Contact for some marketing. Every time I visit their Campaigns page I need to sort the page to get it to display for my specific need. Using Chrome's Inspect feature I can see that their sorting is a Javascript call. They have no way to set defaults for the page. Is there a way to embed in the URL that calls the page, a call to their Javascript to utilize their sort function so that the page displays already sorted my way when I visit the page?

Comment: You could make a JS script to call the function and [put it in a bookmark button](http://www.dev-hq.net/posts/1--create-javascript-bookmarklet) on your browser

Comment: Tampermonkey could be super useful for this. :)

Comment: Consider creating a browser extension for this.

Answer (score -1):

Not in the general case. If there was, it would be down to an [XSS security vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) in the website itself.

If you want to automatically run your code on other people's websites you should look at browser extensions.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than creating an browser extension, you can create a JS script using [Tempermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=fr) that can run automatically when you visit a defined website.

This browser extension allow you to run a script on the document context the same way of an dedicated extension.